# How to tie together custom dependency properties of UserControl with properties of nested controls?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a `UserControl` that includes three `TextBlock` controls. I want to implement three custom properties in `UserControl`. Something like:

```
public partial class MyControl: UserControl
{
    ...
    public String Title
    {
        get { return this.textBlock1.Text; }
        set { this.textBlock1.Text = value; }
    }

    public String Units
    {
        get { return this.textBlock2.Text; }
        set { this.textBlock2.Text = value; }
    }

    public String Data
    {
        get { return this.textBlock3.Text; }
        set { this.textBlock3.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

If I want to use binding capabilities with these properties I have to implement them as dependency properties. Am I right? But I do not know how to do it in my case.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx

Comment: There is a pretty good [How-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN discussing implementing custom dependency properties

Comment: Essence of the question is not how to implement custom dependency properties itself but how to connect custom dependency properties with dependency properties of nested control optionaly including some logic (e.x. converting values, aggregating many values to one. etc.)

Comment: What about converters and multibindings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Binding to dependency properties is quite simple to do. Understanding the mechanics I would suggest looking through MSDN. However to answer your question you provide static dependency properties registered to the user control. Then your getters \ setters reference the property.

Here is a sample line of a dependency property.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a bindable text property to the user control
/// </summary>
public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("", onTextPropertyChanged));

/// <summary>
/// optional static call back handler when the property changed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="o"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
static void onTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = o as UserControl1;
    if (obj == null)
        return;

    //TODO: Changed...
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets \ sets the text
/// </summary>
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set
    {
        if (this.Text != value)
            this.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The above is very simple. We register a dependency property `TextProperty` to `UserControl1`, this property is the type of string and has a default value of "" (as noted in the property meta data). I also provided a static callback handler if you wish to perform additional steps once the property has changed.

You will then see the Text property uses the `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` methods for getting and setting the value of the Text Property.

**UPDATE: Binding to a child element in XAML.**

This update is to show how to use the the above TextProperty for binding.

Usercontrol1.Xaml. This is the XAML for UserControl1.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Text" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="4" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My Main Window View Model (Implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public class MainWindowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// the text
    /// </summary>
    string myProperty = "This is the default text";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets \ sets the text
    /// </summary>
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return this.myProperty;  }
        set
        {
            if (this.MyProperty != value)
            {
                this.myProperty = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// fires the property changed event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the property changed event
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

MainWindow.Xaml. Binding the text property to the view model

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Name="Window1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ctrl:MainWindowModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ctrl:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Window1}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If I want to change some property of nested control where should I place code, i.e. `nestedControl.Property = value`? In `onTextPropertyChanged`?

Comment: So a nested control would be probably best to bind to your dependency property in XAML and then everytime the Usercontrol1.Text is updated then nested control would be updated. I will post and edit with an example of using nested controls.

Comment: Thanks! This approach is suitable to me.

Comment: Two remarks : first, in `UserControl1.xaml`, your implementation forbids the use of a custom `DataContext` for `UserControl1`. A solution is to bind using `RelativeSource FindAncestor` as shown in my answer. Then in MainWindown.xaml `Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Window1}"` -> you could just have defined : `Text="{Binding MyProperty}"` !

Answer (score 0):

Code for the dependency property :

```
  public string Title
  {
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(TitleProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(TitleProperty, value); } 
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = 
                 DependencyProperty.Register("Title",
                                             typeof(string),
                                             typeof(MyControl),
                                             new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Binding in xaml :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                  AncestorType={x:Type yourXmlns:MyControl}}"/>
```